# Google PageSpeed and jpg lossless compression

Tags: compression, jpeg, pagespeed

According to recommendations by Google PageSpeed Insights, I want to lossless compression tool, for JPG images.
Google documentation suggests me use a tool "jpegtran.exe". I tried it with such parameters:

`jpegtran.exe -copy none -optimize -progressive source.jpg result.jpg`

It works, BUT - not good as need. If I download "optimized" resources from page speed diagnostic page (a link at bottom), I see that pictures compressed, and size is SMALLER than I can have with jpegtran. So, question is - do you know a free tool (not online), or special parameters for jpegtran, to create more compressed but lossless images in jpg format?

Answer (score 0):

There are various open source libraries to do that. ImageMagic and GraphicMagic.

You can try [ImageKit.io](https://imagekit.io). This will automatically serve optimized images on your website always. It's free up to a limit.